# Is it a problem to use synthetic ATF as power steering fluid on the Land Rover LR3?

Tags: power-steering, atf, land-rover, lr3

The power steering fluid on my LR3 is brown and muddy, so it needs to be renewed.

My local dealership reckons its power steering fluid should retail at around 167 cola cans per liter.

I have access to a LiquiMoly ATF product that retails for a far more reasonable 50 cola cans per liter:

[LiquiMoly 1200 Top Tec](https://www.liqui-moly.eu/liquimoly/produktdb.nsf/id/en_3680.html) conforms to the following standards:

- Allison C4
- Caterpillar TO-2
- Dexron III H
- Ford Mercon V
- Honda ATF Z1 (ausser CVT)
- Hyundai SP II
- Hyundai SP III
- JASO 1-A
- Kia SP-II
- Kia SP III
- Mazda ATF M III
- Mazda ATF M-V
- Mitsubishi SP-II
- Mitsubishi SP-III
- Nissan AT-Matic D Fluid
- Nissan AT-Matic J Fluid
- Nissan AT-Matic K Fluid
- Toyota Type T-II
- Toyota Type T-IV

Is it possible to use this fluid instead, or do I need to part with more cola cans?

Answer (score 2):

From what I'm reading on various Land Rover forums, the dealer-recommended fluid, Texaco Cold Climate Fluid #14315, is a mineral-oil based fluid. Since this fluid is/was difficult to obtain, many of the posts are stating that a Dexron III compatible *non-synthetic* ATF should work fine as long as ambient temperatures in the area don't dip below -20°C (-4°F).

Also, apparently, Castrol markets a power steering fluid that meets the original fluid's specs (but is unavailable outside the USA).

Links to some of the forum posts:

[Expedition Portal](http://www.expeditionportal.com/forum/threads/138083-LR-3-Best-power-Steering-Fluid)
[Disco-Web.org](https://discoweb.org/forums/showpost.php?p=925954&postcount=25) (lots of info in the thread, this post was the most relevant)
[LR4x4.com](http://forums.lr4x4.com/topic/37126-which-oil-for-ace-pas/)
[Landyzone.co.uk](https://www.landyzone.co.uk/land-rover/texaco-cold-climate-pas-fluid-14315-or-dexron-ii.157132/) (specifically post #8, referring to the Haynes manual)

Comment: Do you have link(s) to the forum posts?